# SerialPort lib - "parsers.readline is not a function" Error - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

I have copied this code:

```
var serialport =require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var portName = process.argv[2];

var myPort = new SerialPort(portName,{
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser:serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
})

myPort.on('open',onOpen);
myPort.on('data',onData);

function onOpen(){
    console.log("Open connections!");
}

function onData(data){
    console.log("on Data "+data);
}
```

from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhagmAv35Kk

I would like to stream the data from serial port from my pc into a NJS code.
when i run the code i get this error:

```
c:\njs>node main.js
C:\njs\main.js:7
        parser:serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
                                  ^

TypeError: serialport.parsers.readline is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\njs\main.js:7:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3

c:\njs>
```

anyone know why it can't recognize the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the version of the module.
accordding to the lastest version this code should do the work:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1');
const parser = new Readline();
port.pipe(parser);
parser.on('data', console.log);
port.write('ROBOT PLEASE RESPOND\n');
```

Answer (score 4):

A working version of your code, you've just to instantiate the `Readline` class :

```
var serialport = require('serialport');
var portName = process.argv[2];

var myPort = new serialport(portName, {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new serialport.parsers.Readline('\r\n')
});

myPort.on('open', onOpen);
myPort.on('data', onData);

function onOpen(){
    console.log('Open connections!');
}

function onData(data){
    console.log('on Data ' + data);
}
```

and you can run using `node index.js COM5`, for example, to get something like this :

```
Open connections!
on Data 123456789
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right Readline is a class not function! Try this:

```
parser: SerialPort.parsers.Readline
```

Check this out and let me know if it works!
https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#serialportparsers--object

Comment: i have saw a couple of times a code with the same arguments, its not a Class.

Comment: https://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/labs/labs-serial-communication/lab-serial-communication-with-node-js/